# Best practice with rxjs for Error handling

Tags: rxjs

In rxjs, errors can be either handled

- when declaring the observable:

```js
const http$ = this.http.get<Course[]>('/api/courses')
      .pipe(catchError(err => of([])));
```

- or/and at subscription time:

```js
 http$.subscribe(
            res => console.log('HTTP response', res),
            err => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
            () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
        );
```

The error handling strategy are well sumarized in:
https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

My understanding is that the first option (handling error in observable declaration) is more powerful. 
I would then be tempted to say that the best practice would be to always and systematically handle errors at that level.
Would you agree with that or are there cases where errors should be handled at subscription time?

Comment: It really depends only on what you want to achieve. With `catchError` you're turning an error into next notification so it'll be processed by your next handler (so is this what you always want?). All subsequent operators will have to handle it as another next notification as well.
If you use just the error handler in subscribers you can have a different logic for error handling. Most other operators just pass through error notifications.

Comment: There is one more thing. The first example will invoke the `next` and `complete` method but if you run it in a real error like in the second example rxjs will terminate the stream. That means it will not invoke `next` and not even `complete` method.